# How to serialize lazy loaded entities with jackson module hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, angularjs, jackson

I`m trying to build an application with angularjs and springmvc.I have two classes Province and Comunidad. :

```
@Entity(name="Provincia")
@Table(name="T_PROVINCIA")
public class Provincia implements Serializable{


private String idProvincia;
private String nombre;    
private Comunidad refComunidad;

public Provincia() {
}

@Id
@TableGenerator(name="provinciaGen",
                table="T_GENERATOR",
                pkColumnName="ID_GENERATOR",
                pkColumnValue="ID_PROVINCIA",
                valueColumnName="ID_VALUE")
@GeneratedValue(generator="provinciaGen",strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name="ID_PROVINCIA")
public String getIdProvincia() {
    return idProvincia;
}

@Column(name="NOMBRE")
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Comunidad.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_COMUNIDAD")
public Comunidad getRefComunidad() {
    return refComunidad;
}
setters
.....
.....
}

@Entity(name="Comunidad")
@Table(name="T_COMUNIDAD")
public class Comunidad implements Serializable{

@Id   
@TableGenerator(name="comunidadGen",
                table="T_GENERATOR",
                pkColumnName="ID_GENERATOR",
                pkColumnValue="ID_COMUNIDAD",
                valueColumnName="ID_VALUE")
@GeneratedValue(generator="comunidadGen",strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name="ID_COMUNIDAD")
private String idComunidad;

@Column(name="NOMBRE")
private String nombre;

@Column(name="SHORTNAME")
private String shortName;

public Comunidad() {
}

getters and setters
...............
}
```

In my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/userlist.json")
public @ResponseBody List<Provincia> getUserList(){
    return this.provinciaService.loadAllProvincias();
}
```

And I get that error:
    /*
    No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer and
    no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
    SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: 
    java.util.ArrayList[0]->admin.domain.Provincia["refComunidad"]-<
    admin.domain.Comunidad$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$68ea9e6f["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
    */

I have read on github about jackson module hibernate is a good choice to solve the
problem : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-hibernate.
I included the jackson module hibernate dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But I don't know where configure the "Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING,true".
I try to follow the indications from that page http://blog.pastelstudios.com/2012/03/12/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-jackson-module-hibernate/

but I obtain the same error.

Is there somebody who can help me with an easy example please?

Answer (score 12):

You can try this. It helps to me.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Hibernate4Module hbm = new Hibernate4Module();
hbm.enable(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);

mapper.registerModule(hbm);
ObjectWriter w = mapper.writer();
String result = null;
try {
    result = w.writeValueAsString(o);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I got it working, i'm using RestEASY on JBoss WildFly

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned... Too long ago to retrace. It were probably recent versions when I started using them, early 2015

Comment: aight, I'm not sure but I don't think this works in Jackson 2.x and RESTEasy Jackson 2 provider 3.x. I need someone else to test it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact problem and here is my solution.

```
public class YourObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        getSerializationConfig().set(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    }
}
```

p/s: Only valid for `1.9.x org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` and not 2.x Jackson.

Comment: For Jackson 2.x, use

`ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();`
`MAPPER.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);`

That said, neither of these answers seemed to help my similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know is a little bit late, but here is the solution for your problem: [Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects/21760361#21760361)