# Correct way to use retrieve external object with Lazy fetch type

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

I'm using Spring, Hibernate and MySql and I set fetchType as LAZY to improve performance of my software because with EAGER it was very slow.
Now I need to retrieve information of external object linked to my class, for example I have `Car` class:

```
/**
 * Car generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "car", catalog = "ats")
public class Car implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer idCar;
private CarType carType;
private Fleet fleet;
private String id;
private int initialKm;
private String carChassis;
private String note;
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Acquisition> acquisitions = new HashSet<Acquisition>(0);
```

and I need `carType` id. So if I use

```
public List<Car> findByFleetIdFleet(int idFleet);
```

I retrieve an exception because I put the result in another my class TableUi (used to allow ajax call from table):

```
public class TableUI {

   private Object data;

/**
 * @return the data
 */
public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

/**
 * @param data the data to set
 */
public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```

and my controller return `@ResponseBody TableUI`. Obviously Jackson can't map the object because its fields fleet and carType are only proxy.
This is the exception:

```
    ERROR com.controller.ErrorController - org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.model.tablesField.TableUI["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.domain.Car["carType"]->com.domain.CarType_$$_jvst4de_f["handler"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.model.tablesField.TableUI["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.domain.Car["carType"]->com.domain.CarType_$$_jvst4de_f["handler"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:271)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.model.tablesField.TableUI["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.domain.Car["carType"]->com.domain.CarType_$$_jvst4de_f["handler"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:128)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:602)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:264)
    ... 37 more

.11:24:38.387 [http-nio-8086-exec-4] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.model.tablesField.TableUI["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.domain.Car["carType"]->com.domain.CarType_$$_jvst4de_f["handler"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.model.tablesField.TableUI["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.domain.Car["carType"]->com.domain.CarType_$$_jvst4de_f["handler"])
```

Instead if I use `findByFleetIdFleet` in `model.addAttribute` it works
So I need another method that return carType with Car object that I use only when I need further information (JOIN FETCH works with one object, if I need all objects?).
The only working way that I have found is this:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<CarWithCarType> findByFleetIdFleetFetch(int idFleet) {
            String jpql = "select f from Fleet f where f.idFleet = :idFleet";
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
            query.setParameter("idFleet", idFleet);
            Fleet fleet=(Fleet) query.getSingleResult();
            String jpql2 = "select c from Car c JOIN FETCH c.carType where c.fleet = :fleet";
            Query query2 = entityManager.createQuery(jpql2);
            query2.setParameter("fleet", fleet);
            List<Car> cars= query2.getResultList();
            List<CarWithCarType> carsList = new ArrayList<CarWithCarType>();
            for (Car car: cars){
                CarWithCarType newCar = new CarWithCarType();
                newCar.setId(car.getId());
                newCar.setCarChassis(car.getCarChassis());
                newCar.setCarType(car.getCarType());
                newCar.setIdCar(car.getIdCar());
                newCar.setInitialKm(car.getInitialKm());
                newCar.setNote(car.getNote());
                carsList.add(newCar);
            }
            return carsList;
        }
```

Is it the best way or there are some other better ways?Thanks

**UPDATE**:
This is jackson hibernate mapping configuration adde to my config class:

```
   public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
```

no exception was thrown but I receive null in the carType and fleet:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "idCar": 4,
      "carType": null,
      "fleet": null,
      "id": "06",
      "initialKm": 1000,
      "carChassis": "VPNEWCAR",
      "note": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

so I used ***Hibernate.initialize(car.getCarType());*** and it works. Is it correctly?

Comment: Did you get LazyInitializationException?

Comment: no, I update with stacktrace

Comment: I believe the proxy object comes with the id(`proxy.getId()`), so you could make another DB call passing forth the id and get the full object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solutions is (use one of them):

1. Configure [hibernate module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate).
2. Use data transfer objects (DTO's) and any mapping utility like Dozer or ModelMapper.

**UPD:**
Now call for Hibernate4Module `hbm.enable(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);`
Of cource you can initialize manually, but this solution is much simpler.

Comment: 1) What is the difference with EAGER?Does it always serialize all the object?
2) It's copy in another bean, but the query has to do anyway

Comment: 1) EAGER makes the query to db immediatly after retrieving Car.
2) I've not understood...

You have exception from Jackson. Are you configured it correctly? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17568603/2221168

Comment: You should if you want to solve the problem. Is there any obstacles to use it?

Comment: FORCE_LAZY_LOADING fills all the external object? Isn't it heavier than use another class with only the needed object and call it when needs ?

Comment: Heavier - it may load fields that you don't need. You can use [Jackson Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) for this issue

Comment: So, I think is easier to use hibernate but I could have need Jackson Views in the future. Thanks

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct if you consider it so. Thanks.